# Include magento email template into another email template in Admin panel

Tags: email, magento, templates, magento-1.7

In magento 1.9.1 there is a option called custom email header. which allows to include an email template into other email template. So if we make a changes in header it will reflected in all the email template. How to implement the same kind of feature for magento EE 1.13? . Is there any option to include email template into another template using email template code?

Do i need to create custom variable?

Please kindly help me. Thankz

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution what you are searching for https://github.com/WysiwygEmail/Magento-Email-Template-Builder

The free open source editor does exactly what are you looking for. In this case you will get the same results for EE as with the Magento CE. It generates the same kinds of header.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)